# Angular Doesn't Recognize karma.conf.js

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner

In a commercial project, tests have been running fine for some time. We cut a release in Angular 8. On master, we upgrade to Angular 9. Now the release needs a hotfix, so I check the branch out and run tests. This is all in the same repo / file system directory.

It fails like `Angular core has no exported member ɵɵFactoryDef` and I quickly determine that the [error is due to CLI version incompatibility](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35291).

So I uninstall ng CLI globally and reinstall `npm i -g @angular/cli@8.2.0`, in line with the release branch package.json. Now the above error is gone, but when I try to `ng test` the CLI insists that karma.conf doesn't exist. The only issue is that, like, it totally does exist.

Other things I have tried:

1. `rm -rf` and `npm i` from scratch
2. `npm cache verify`
3. close and re-open terminals
4. restart computer
5. create a new karma.conf with a different name and point angular.json to that

ng cli does respect angular.json in that the below error will change depending on my karma file name and path, but it still continues to insist, on MacOS, that the below file doesn't exist:
On Mac, I still get:
`ERROR [config]: File /Users/<various paths that totally exist>/src/karma.<tried different things here>.js does not exist!`

Any ideas? Thanks!!

--- Edit: adding some technical info below per request.

test block from `angular.json`:

```
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "codeCoverage": true,
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "node_modules/jquery-mockjax/dist/jquery.mockjax.js"],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*.html",
                                "input": "./src/legacy",
                                "output": "./"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

Partial client folder structure. Notice that `storybook/` and `test/` are siblings of `src/`, and angular.json is one level above `src/. I have already tried some karma path mutations including:

1. `"karmaConfig": "./src/karma.conf.js",`
2. `"karmaConfig": "../../<correct folders>src/karma.conf.js",`
3. `"karmaConfig": "src/karma.<change this>.js",`

[image: partial angular client folder structure]

Comment: can u update config file here.. seems issue with setting and snapshot of folder structure

Comment: @xdeepakv I've shared what I can involving angular.json and folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up solving it for me, after steps mentioned in the question:

1. Delete the entire repo
2. Re-clone (actually, I did a shallow clone `git clone <repo-url>.git --branch <ng8-branch> --depth 5`
3. Install again `npm i`

Now `ng test` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You might have gone through this check already but have you tried updating your `package.json` to have the path of karma.conf like so...?

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ./path_to_karma.conf.js"
}
```

Comment: good check, but I'm using `ng test` rather than invoking `karma start`. `ng test` uses the karma path as `karmaConfig` property of the `angular.json`, and I did check this under item 5 in the question.